# How to create a matrix in SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, matrix, sql-server-2012

I have to do data monitoring in the database. Due to security features I am not given admin rights.

I have to create a matrix where I have to count the rows the database has on a unique key everyday.

So currently I run the query everyday:

```sql
select Count(Uniquekey)
from TableName 
where RecordCreatedDate < '2021-09-14' 
order by RecordCreatedDate desc
```

Then I create a table in Excel where I write

```
Date_For_Data Date_data_checked Count 
09/09/2021     09/09/2021       100
10/09/2021     10/09/2021       120 
11/09/2021     11/09/2021       130
12/09/2021     12/09/2021       134
```

I run this query 4 times. But next day I shall do it 5 times and on. Can I create a matrix in SQL itself. It shall save lots of time.

Comment: What do you mean can you create a matrix in SQL Server? A matrix is something you find in your presentation layer, not the database.

Comment: That query you have, by the way, will error. `RecordCreatedDate` isn't in the `GROUP BY` so can't be ordered on.

Comment: Use SQL Server Reporting Services and save yourself all the headache.

Answer (score 0):

You could group by the `RecordCreatedDate`:

```sql
SELECT   RecordCreatedDate, COUNT(Uniquekey)
FROM     TableName 
GROUP BY RecordCreatedDate
```

Comment: Thankyou. This will show entries done every day. I would also need total entries in the database on that day. So i will need Date, entries done on that day, total rows in the database on that day. Is that possible too ?

Comment: Hi , I was thinking, i can add a column (Lets say Counterdatabase) in the database with default value 1. Now i can write  SELECT   COUNT(Uniquekey), sum(counterdatabase)
FROM     TableName 
GROUP BY RecordCreatedDate. I think that should work. But do you know how to add a column in the database with a set value = 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a job daily running, which tracks unique key for the previous day as given below:

```sql
DECLARE @table table(uniquekey int unique, recordcreateddate date);

insert into @table 
values (1,'2021-09-11'),(2,'2021-09-11'),(3,'2021-09-12'),(4,'2021-09-13');

SELECT cast(dateadd(dd,-1,getdate()) as date) as Date_For_Data, cast(getdate() as date) as Date_data_checked, count(uniquekey) as [Count]   FROM @table
where RecordCreatedDate = cast(dateadd(dd,-1,getdate()) as date)
```

| Date_For_Data | Date_data_checked | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-13 | 2021-09-14 | 1 |

Comment: Hi There, Thankyou! This is exactly what i want. I just want another column with total rows in the database on that date too. With group by that is not possible. Can i somehow use over(partition by) or any function , in such a way so that i am able to show total of rows in the database ? Thanks again

Comment: @paru80, please ask that as a separate question. changes to question will confuse future users of the site. If it answers your question, please mark it as answer. so, it will be helpful for others in future.